# when to use authenticatable interface laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm starting to developing in laravel 5.3/5.4 and I have found some basic and some advance tuts for creating models and eloquent clases. But in the way some examples are using models and implementing **Authenticatable Contract interface** so my question is: When to use this interface??

Now in code maybe we can use something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Session;

class Appointment extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract{

    use authenticatable;

    protected $fillable = array('something');

    public function etcetera()
    {
      //some code...
    }

    //more code...
}
```

Or just something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Patient extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['something'];
}

//more code...
```

I hope you guys can help me to clarify the use of this implementation and when to apply it to a certain model